# Question on Linear Algebra Particular Solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been recently learning Linear Algebra using an online course before University starts to be able to get ahead.

To illustrate my question, consider a 3x4 matrix A with rank 2. (And 2 free variables consequently)
In solving Ax=b, there are 2 free variables. In the lecture I was watching, they stated that the free variables can be set to zero for convenience, then the solution can be added to the nullspace of A to yield the full solutions for Ax=b.

However, why does setting the free variables to zero yield all solutions? Can I not make those variables other numbers and get out another set of vectors which satisfy Ax=b?

I can sort of visualise why this may be the case, but I don't have access to any plotting devices to be able to fully see why any other values of free variables will still give a vector x in the set of solutions.

Thanks

Comment: To solve $Ax=b$ it is enough to have *one* solution $x_0$ of $Ax=b$ and *all* solutions $x_r$ of $Ax=0$. Setting the free variables to zero is a way to find and pick a choice for $x_0$. Then for arbitrary values of the free variables you solve for the others to obtain a parametric form $x_r$ of all solutions of $Ax=0$. Finally, all solutions of $Ax=b$ are of the form $x_0+x_r$.

Comment: If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both solutions to $Ax=b$, then $A(x_1 - x_2) = Ax_1 - Ax_2 = b - b = 0$, so $x_1 - x_2$ is in the nullspace. So $x_2$ equals $x_1$ plus some element of the nullspace. In other words, given an arbitrary particular solution (in this case $x_1$), *every* solution equals $x_1$ plus some element of the nullspace. If your $x_1$ happens to be a particular solution where you set the free variables to zero, this result still holds.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that by proving that the solutions of a linear system of equations $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ is precisely the set
$$
S=\lbrace\mathbf{p}+\mathbf{h}:A\mathbf{p}=\mathbf{b},\mathbf{h}\in null(A)\rbrace,
$$
where $null(A)$ is the nullspace of $A$ (I'll refer to solutions of $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ as *particular solutions*). That can be seen from the fact that if $\mathbf{u}\in S$, $A\mathbf{u}=A(\mathbf{p}+\mathbf{h})=A\mathbf{p}+A\mathbf{h}=\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{b}$ (for some $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{h}$ such that $A\mathbf{p}=\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{h}\in null(A)$), so $\mathbf{u}$ is a particular solution. Conversely, if $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{p}$ are particular solutions ($A\mathbf{u}=A\mathbf{p}=\mathbf{b}$), then $A(\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{p})=A\mathbf{u}-A\mathbf{p}=\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{0}$, so $\mathbf{h}=\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{p}\in null(A)$ and $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{p}+\mathbf{h}$, where $\mathbf{p}$ is a particular solution and $\mathbf{h}$ is in the nullspace, so $\mathbf{u}\in S$. From here we conclude that the set of solutions for $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ is our set $S$ made of the sum of a particular solution with every element of the nullspace. So to solve a system of equations we can just find one solution for $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ and then every solution for $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ ($null(A)$), and the easiest and most convenient way to find a particular solution is to let all of the free variables equal to zero (however, note that any particular solution would work, we just do that for simplicity in calculations).

On a sidenote, the fact that $S$ is the sum of a "point" with a vector space (the nullspace) makes the set of solutions of a system of equations an affine space. That makes the whole thing easier to understand, because a particular solution is a point of the subspace, and the nullspace is the set of all vectors we can add to our starting point to reach any other point in our subspace.